# Deleted file is not showing up in the recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to delete a file from the SharePoint website. However, after deleting the file, it's not showing up in Recycle Bin and it's not decreasing space from the website as well.

I read something about a secondary storage recycling bin but I am not sure where to find it.

The site I am trying to delete stuff from is a sub-site, not sure if that matters?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Recycle bin

[image] (Source: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1064)

In this Recycle bin you can see all deleted items (even subsite's items).

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online sites offer end-user and site collection administrator views to the Recycle Bin. The end user can see any items he or she deleted, but the site collection administrator can see all items deleted by any user within the site collection.

To display the Second-Stage Recycle Bin:
On the left navigation pane of the Team Site page, choose Recycle Bin.
On the Site Collection Recycle Bin page choose second-stage recycle bin.
Choose second-stage recycle-bin link.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-Recycle-Bin-of-a-SharePoint-Online-site-collection-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1